# how to get the rowID in jqGrid is data based on the data in the column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Im trying to get the rowID of a particular row in jqGrid where on of the columns of jqGrid contains the specific data.

for e.g. if one of the columns in the row is "instanceNum" than i want to do the comparison first with the "instanceNum" stored in an array with the "instanceNum" displayed in the column.If both "instanceNum" matches than i need to get the id of that row.

I'm new to this jqGrid so please help me out or guide me in the right direction.thanks

Comment: You should include JavaScript code which shows how you fill the data. Because the data in the grid exists not always and the data will be changed (on loading, on sorting and so on) one speak typically about rowid **only inside of callbacks or events of jqGrid**. You wrote that you need "to get the rowID". It's important to knoq *what you need to do with the rowid?* Do you need make some modifications of style of the rows? If you just need analyse the data then you can do this *on the server side* and not in jqGrid. So more details required to be able to help you.

Comment: i found a workaround this issue.But now im experiencing new problem and its that initially im displaying only 15rows per page(here rowIDs ranges from 1-15),now when the use increases the numbers of rows using pagination or if user goes to page#2 the rowIDs should range from 16-30 and not 1-15.For e.eg if user chose to to move to next page where another 15 records are shown.here i expect the rowIDs to range from 16-30.But the problem is that rowID still ranges from 1-15 and whatever logic i tend to implement based on rowID fails.Please help thanks

Comment: **You have to post the JavaScript code which you use inclusive the test data which you use** (two rows of data would be enough). The problem is that the `rowid` is **not the same as the row index**. You have to include rowid in you data. If you on't do this jqGrid have to generate ids for rows. The current version use numbers like 1, 2, 3, ... in the case.